# Incompatibility with Grails plug in?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I'm creating a Grails application which makes use of the RichUI plug in and the Atmosphere plug in. However, it looks like there's some sort of incompatibility with these plug ins. When I declare the resources tag in the head of the .gsp page, only one of the plug ins works correctly. If I declare like this:

```
<head>
  <atmosphere:resources/>
  <resource:rating />
     ...
```

only works the RichUI plug in (star rating). In the other way around it only works the atmosphere plug in:

```
<head>
  <resource:rating />
  <atmosphere:resources/>
   ...
```

Any idea why is this happening? Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks very much.

**UPDATE**

This are the resources being imported in the gsp page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Ontourtest/plugins/atmosphere-0.4.1/js/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Ontourtest/plugins/atmosphere-0.4.1/js/jquery.atmosphere.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='/Ontourtest/plugins/richui-0.8/js/prototype/prototype.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/Ontourtest/plugins/richui-0.8/js/rating/behavior.js'></script><script type='text/javascript' src='/Ontourtest/plugins/richui-0.8/js/rating/rating.js'></script><link rel='stylesheet' href='/Ontourtest/plugins/richui-0.8/css//rating.css'></link>
```

Can you see any potential incompatibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a method name collision; both plugins may declare same-named functions in the default namespace. I've used [YUI Namespacing](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yahoo/#namespace) to resolve this in my apps.

It could also be a conflict in plugin dependencies, such as each importing a different version of the same library. Try viewing the generated html of your gsp page to see what the plugin resource tags are importing.

**edit:**

I took a quick look through those Javascript libraries and the collision is likely the "$" token being used differently by JQuery (used by Atmosphere) and Prototype (used by RichUI).

According to the [JQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict), calling "noConflict()" as below should resolve things. Keep in mind I haven't tried this and I don't know if the component .js files will now work without further modification:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've updated the post with the resources being imported in the gsp page. Can you see any potential incompatibilites?